# How data in an HDFS block is stored?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I was reading about HDFS and was wondering, if there is any specific format in which data in a block is arranged.

Suppose there is a file of 265 MB that is copied to a Hadoop cluster and the HDFS block size is 64 MB. So the file is broken into 5 parts- 64 MB + 64 MB + 64 MB + 64 MB + 9 MB, and distributed among data nodes. Correct ?

1. I have a doubt that is there any format within the 64 MB block in which data is stored ?
2. If there is any format/structure in which the data is stored within the block, then the stored data should be less than 64 MB, since the data structure/header etc, itself may take some space.
3. Since HDFS data node is a logical filesystem (It runs on top of linux and there is no separate partition for HDFS), all the blocks should be stored as files in the linux partition. Correct ?
4. How to know the name of the file on linux that actually stores the 64 MB HDFS block ?

Anyone, if can answer these doubts/questions, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

(*Vipul)() ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, the data is just split on 64MB boundary. Metadata is stored in a small separate file and on the Namenode
2. No, it is exactly the size you specified, and the data is split on exact boundaries of 64MB. If you have 5 parts - 64 MB + 64 MB + 64 MB + 64 MB + 9 MB, then the last file would be 9MB, all the others are 64MB
3. Yes, the blocks are stored as a files, each block is represented as a separate file with some small amount of metadata stored in a separate file
4. `hdfs fsck / -files -blocks -locations`

Here's an example of how the block files are stored with 128MB block size:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 134217728 Jan 12 09:17 blk_1073741825
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop   1048583 Jan 12 09:17 blk_1073741825_1001.meta
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 134217728 Jan 12 09:18 blk_1073741826
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop   1048583 Jan 12 09:18 blk_1073741826_1002.meta
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 134217728 Jan 12 09:18 blk_1073741827
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop   1048583 Jan 12 09:18 blk_1073741827_1003.meta
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 134217728 Jan 12 09:18 blk_1073741828
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop   1048583 Jan 12 09:18 blk_1073741828_1004.meta
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 134217728 Jan 12 09:19 blk_1073741829
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop   1048583 Jan 12 09:19 blk_1073741829_1005.meta
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop 134217728 Jan 12 09:19 blk_1073741830
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop   1048583 Jan 12 09:19 blk_1073741830_1006.meta
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop  87776064 Jan 12 09:19 blk_1073741831
-rw-r--r--. 1 hdfs hadoop    685759 Jan 12 09:19 blk_1073741831_1007.meta
```

Comment: Thanks 0x0FFF, I executed the command you specified "hadoop fsck / -files -blocks -locations" which gave a long result and lines like this -

*/user/vpathak/testData/u.item 236344 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK*
*0. blk_-7097388478926784482_1004 len=236344 repl=1 [127.0.0.1:50010]*

However, how to know where the block "blk_7097388478926784482_1004" is stored on my Linux Filesystem ?

Comment: You can execute this command for a single file, not for the whole filesystem: `hdfs fsck /user/vpathak/testData/u.item -files -blocks -locations`. As you can see from the output, the file is located at `[127.0.0.1:50010]`, which is the IP and port of the datanode stores the block. Go to the `hdfs-site.xml` file on this datanode and see the parameter `dfs.datanode.data.dir` - it is the directory (or list of directories) where the physical blocks are stored. Now that you know the directory and the block name you can easily find it

Comment: Got it, Thank you. Another thing that I was wondering about was the number if InputSplits that are created by the Map/Reduce framework for each Block.

How the framework decide about the number of input splits to create -
  (a) When the property telling Map and Reduce tasks count, is set.

Comment: In short, it completely depends on the InputFormat class you use. In the simplest case of TextInputFormat it would be one input split for one block of HDFS data, except by the case when the whole file is compressed using non-splittable algo (like gzipped text file), in this case you would have one input split for the whole file

Comment: Great, but is it possible to create Multiple input splits from one block on one node ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. You should extend the FileInputFormat class (https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java) and override the getSplits method to return any splits you like. You can even pass desired split size as a parameter through configuration object (JobConf)

Comment: So, lets say if FileInptFormat is overridden and we return 4 splits from the getSplits() method for each 64 MB block. This means Map/Reduce will create 4 Mapper tasks on the same node, processing 16 MBs of data each in parallel, correct ?
(OR)
It will be 1 Mapper task processing all the 4 splits one at a time ?

Comment: MR framework schedules one mapper for each input split, in this case there would be 4 mappers processing 16MB each (and not necessary on the same node, it is just a preference, but not mandatory)

Comment: Nice to know. I was under an impression that everything related to a block will be processed on the same node where it is stored (for the sake of data locality principal). Didn't knew that even InputSplits of the same block can be processed on different nodes.

Comment: Yes, they can, even on a different rack. Map tasks are completely independent and are scheduled independently